# Print multiple lines in place

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, console

```
for index in range(0, len(order_of_fruits)):
    maze[prevY][prevX] = ' '
    curr = order_of_fruits[index]
    maze[curr[1]][curr[0]] = 'P'
    prevX = curr[0]
    prevY = curr[1]

    result_maze = ""
    for i in range(len(maze)):
        for j in range(len(maze[0])):
            result_maze = result_maze + maze[i][j]
        result_maze = result_maze + '\n'

    animation.append(result_maze)

#animate
for index in range(0, len(animation)):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(animation[index]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Hi, my problem is that I have a two-dimentionay array whose condition will update. Then I convert each updated array to a string and append each string to a list which are used to print in the console. Now I want print the changing condition of this maze which have already been converted to string in place. I used the "\r" and flush but it does not work. I guess this might because I have "\n" in each of my string. So is there any way that I can print the series of maze in console in place? So the result looks like only one maze appears on the console whose condition will update every 0.2?
Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 0):

"\r" maybe put in the end of line.

```
import time
for index in range(0, len(animation)):
    sys.stdout.write(str(animation[index]) + "\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks! but this not working. I hope only one will appear and keep updating, but this still generate a lot........

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/curses.html) module. This program  updates the screen, waits 0.2 seconds, and updates the screen again:

```
from curses import wrapper
import time

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    for i in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            for x in range(5):
                stdscr.addstr(y, x, chr(ord('1')+i))
            stdscr.refresh()
            time.sleep(0.2)
    stdscr.getkey()

wrapper(main)
```